# Laravel auth with subdomain | Auth for multidomains

Tags: laravel, authentication

I want implement auth from subdomain.
For example..
Domains:

- Login/Register page: auth.mysite.com
- User dashboard: my.mysite.com

Route.php:

```
Route::domain('auth.mysite.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/login', "SomeControlle@login");
    Route::get('/register', "SomeControlle@register");
});
Route::domain('my.mysite.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', "SomeControlle@dashboard");
    Route::get('/', "SomeControlle@index");
    // and others
});
```

And I want this auth work with other domains which are connected to my project. (mysite2.com, notmysite.com)
Users should only have to login once and it will work for every one of my domains, but I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change in config/session.php:

```
'domain' => '.mysite.com,
```